My app returns all keywords instead of existing in the string list in ml.net and c#
In an application for a law article, there is a list of strings with keywords. In the example it is assigned to the variable keywords.
In my example there is an article with the title İşçilik Alacaklarında Kısmi Dava ve Belirsiz Alacak Davası Müesseselerinin İşletilmesi. Using ML.Net, I want to derive keywords similar to those in the list assigned to the keywords variable from the article title. I wrote the following code for this:
public class InputData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class TransformedData
{
    public float[] Features { get; set; }
}

private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mlContext = new MLContext();

    // List with the given texts
    var inputData = new List<InputData>
    {
        new() { Text = "İşçilik Alacaklarında Kısmi Dava ve Belirsiz Alacak Davası Müesseselerinin İşletilmesi" }
    };

    // Given keywords
    var keywords = new List<string> { "kısmi dava", "üçüncü kişi", "işçi", "işçilik alacakları", "vazife maluliyeti", "belirsiz alacak davası", "yabancı banka", "adli yargı", "anonim şirket", "ayni hak", "ayni hak talebi", "bohçacı sözleşmesi" };

    var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(inputData);

    // TF-IDF transformation
    var textPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Features", new TextFeaturizingEstimator.Options
    {
        WordFeatureExtractor = new WordBagEstimator.Options { NgramLength = 1, UseAllLengths = false },
        Norm = TextFeaturizingEstimator.NormFunction.Infinity,
        KeepPunctuations = false,
        StopWordsRemoverOptions = new StopWordsRemovingEstimator.Options()
    }, "Text");

    var textTransformer = textPipeline.Fit(data);
    var transformedData = textTransformer.Transform(data);

    // Define the schema of the transformed data
    var transformedDataPreview = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<TransformedData>(transformedData, reuseRowObject: false).ToList();

    // Identify keywords
    foreach (var transformedRow in transformedDataPreview)
    {
        var features = transformedRow.Features;
        for (var i = 0; i < features.Length; i++)
        {
            if (features[i] > 0.0 && i < keywords.Count)
            {
                var word = keywords[i];
                MessageBox.Show(word);
            }
        }
    }
}

When I run the code, it returns all the keywords in the list assigned to the keywords variable. However, the keywords that should be returned correctly are: işçilik alacakları, kısmi dava and belirsiz alacak davası
I couldn't find where I went wrong.

Your code shows you initializing the keywords variable, but nowhere in your code do you then do anything with it, such as passing it to the ML.NET service... and you're using the same index i in both features[i] and keywords[i] - that is not a meaningful operation.

@Dai - First of all thank you for your answer. I am a lawyer, software is my hobby. So I can express that it took me a day to create this code.  I have no idea how to solve this problem.

A simple solution using regex:
First, we must remove the accents from your text to make matching easier. Then, we can use the indices returned by the Regex to index into the input data to retrieve the original accented string. This approach is similar to extinctsion's approach, however, they differ in the normalization, stripping, and Regex use. Feel free to delete WriteLines() and or replace them with messageboxes.
I agree with t2solve in the fact that this problem does not need to be solved by AI. If your goal is to find similar text, not precise matches, then that needs to be specified. My answer finds precise matches, a decision guided by your expected outputs. There isn't usually a "correct" answer for AI. Similarity is also subjective, so clarification in what you want would be beneficial if you wanted answers specific to what you really wanted.
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

//Removes Diacritics from a string; credit to Blair Conrad and Marcel Popescu
string RemoveDiacritics(string text)
{
    var normalizedString = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity: normalizedString.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = normalizedString[i];
        var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);
        if (unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder
        .ToString()
        .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}

public class InputData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Original inputs and keywords
    var inputData = new List<InputData>
    {
        new() { Text = "İşçilik Alacaklarında Kısmi Dava ve Belirsiz Alacak Davası Müesseselerinin İşletilmesi" }
    };

    var keywords = new List<string> { "kısmi dava", "üçüncü kişi", "işçi", "işçilik alacakları", "vazife maluliyeti", "belirsiz alacak davası", "yabancı banka", "adli yargı", "anonim şirket", "ayni hak", "ayni hak talebi", "bohçacı sözleşmesi" };

    //Remove diacritics from both OriginalInput and keywords
    string strippedInput = RemoveDiacritics(inputData);
    List<string> strippedKeywords = keywords.Select(RemoveDiacritics).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Stripped Input: " + strippedInput);
    Console.WriteLine("Stripped Keywords: " + string.Join(", ", strippedKeywords));
    Console.WriteLine();

    //Convert stripped keywords to regexes. The @"[^ ]*" matches until a space character.
    Regex[] regexMatchForeachKeyword = strippedKeywords.Select(keyword => new Regex(keyword + "[^ ]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).ToArray();
    List<Match> matches = new();

    //Find and record matches
    foreach (Regex regex in regexMatchForeachKeyword)
    {
        Match m = regex.Match(strippedInput);

        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{regex} matched: " + m + $" (Index: {m.Index}, Length: {m.Length})");
            matches.Add(m);
        }
    }

    //Return matches
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("All matches: " + string.Join(", ", matches));
    string[]  matchesWithDiacritics = matches.Select(match => inputData[match.Index..(match.Index + match.Length)]).ToArray();
}

Here's the output from the code I quickly ran:
Stripped Input: Iscilik Alacaklarında Kısmi Dava ve Belirsiz Alacak Davası Muesseselerinin Isletilmesi

Stripped Keywords: kısmi dava, ucuncu kisi, isci, iscilik alacakları, vazife maluliyeti, belirsiz alacak davası, yabancı banka, adli yargı, anonim sirket, ayni hak, ayni hak talebi, bohcacı sozlesmesi


kısmi dava[^ ]* matched: Kısmi Dava (Index: 22, Length: 10)
isci[^ ]* matched: Iscilik (Index: 0, Length: 7)
iscilik alacakları[^ ]* matched: Iscilik Alacaklarında (Index: 0, Length: 21)
belirsiz alacak davası[^ ]* matched: Belirsiz Alacak Davası (Index: 36, Length: 22)

All matches: Kısmi Dava, Iscilik, Iscilik Alacaklarında, Belirsiz Alacak Davası

If İşçilik should not be a keyword because it is already contained in İşçilik Alacaklarında, then you can do a quick check after the matches are complete to make sure there are no duplicates or check during the matching process itself, but that's a bit more complicated.
If you want more speed with the Regex, you can precompile the Regex using the built-in RegexGenerator attribute, which compiles the Regex to assembly for faster execution. Because your keywords are variable, and there may be many of them, creating compiled regex for each of your keywords may be difficult. You can read more about the RegexGenerator here.
If you want the real string with diacritics returned, use the Regex's information to do so, which would look something like:
string[] matchesWithDiacritics = matches.Select(match => OriginalInput[match.Index .. (match.Index + match.Length])).ToArray();

Just so you know, running this 100,000 times on the title given took around 276ms on my computer (Macbook Pro 2018), which is less than 0.003ms per title.
I hope this helps!
~Complex

Introduction
Here, I have tried to achieve the goal but using a different approach. While implementing searches, the main goal is to match the input letters/words with the letter/words we have in our database.
What was wrong with your code?
You were trying to map the transformed features back to the keywords. The transformed features generated by the TF-IDF transformation do not directly map to the indices of the keywords in your list. The TF-IDF transformation vectorizes the text based on the entire vocabulary it learns from the data, and this vocabulary is NOT directly related to the list of keywords you have.
Simple approach:

Input Normalization: We can simplify our input by ignoring the Upper case words or removing the punctuations from the input.
Direct Matching of letters: We can use LINQ Where clause to direct match each letters.
Displayed only matched keywords: Only matched keywords are displayed using MessageBox.Show.

Why this method?
It is because this method effectively matches the predefined words directly within the article area, ensuring correct matches and removing unnecessary complexities.
Alternate solution
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class InputData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Title of the article
    var inputData = new List<InputData>
    {
        new() { Text = "İşçilik Alacaklarında Kısmi Dava ve Belirsiz Alacak Davası Müesseselerinin İşletilmesi" }
    };

    // Given keywords in List<string>
    var keywords = new List<string> { "kısmi dava", "üçüncü kişi", "işçi", "işçilik alacakları", "vazife maluliyeti", "belirsiz alacak davası", "yabancı banka", "adli yargı", "anonim şirket", "ayni hak", "ayni hak talebi", "bohçacı sözleşmesi" };

    // Normalize the title text
    var normalizedTitle = NormalizeText(inputData[0].Text);

    // Find matching keywords
    var matchingKeywords = keywords.Where(keyword => normalizedTitle.Contains(NormalizeText(keyword))).ToList();

    // Display matching keywords after matching the keywords
    foreach (var keyword in matchingKeywords)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(keyword);
    }
}

private string NormalizeText(string text)
{
    // Convert to lowercase, remove punctuation and extra whitespace from the input
    return Regex.Replace(text.ToLower(), @"\p{P}+", "").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", "").Trim();
}


This approach will be efficient as it is optimized using LINQ and hope this helps to find the solution. Happy coding!

"This approach will be efficient as it is optimized using LINQ" - First, your approach is not efficient, secondly: using Linq does not inhernetly make anything more efficient - in fact, you're actually using Linq such that this method has O(n^2) time-complexity (.Where( k => nt.Contains( NormalizeText( k )) <-- yikes ). There are also other subtle bugs present, such as using text.ToLower(), and chaining .Replace() and .Trim() when a single StringBuilder loop can do it in a single iteration.

@extinctsion - This example you gave is not a solution, and it also broke my desire to develop an AI application based on machine learning. Now I am in complete despair. Thank you...

I did not see a code snipped related to ML.Net.

i do think @extinctsion answer is write here, there is absolutely no need to solve your problem with an ai based solution (ml net). I do think the question is "Solution Looking for a Problem." a better tool for this kind of problem: finding keywords in texts is the c# port of lucene (search engine) https://lucenenet.apache.org/
